# error in Xquery update ( eXistdb)

Tags: xquery-update, exist-db

when i am trying toupdate data into database i found following error'XQuery update expressions can not be applied to in-memory nodes.'...how to resolve this anyone help me....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation on eXist clearly specifies that update doesn't work on in-memory nodes. It only works on XMLs that are persisted in the database. Here is the link:

http://exist.sourceforge.net/update_ext.html